# Generating a JSON object on server plus iterating it on client-side

Tags: php, javascript, iterator, json

My php side

```
   $i = 1;
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
       $productarray[$i][] = $row['product_id'];
       $productarray[$i][] = $row['product_model'];
       $productarray[$i][] = $row['product_type'];
       $productarray[$i][] = $row['product_return'];
       $i++;
    }
    $jsonstring = json_encode($productarray);
```

This is what im getting Is this a valid json string

```
{
 "1":["1","HFJ5G1.5","plat","graviteits"],
 "2":["2","HHJ5S2.5","holle plunjer","veer"],
 "3":["3","HTJ5S7.5","inbouw","veer"]
}
```

i cant iterate through this someone please tell me how to iterate this json

From the json site i think this is the format if so how can i change the above json string to this format ?

```
{
 "1":[{"1","HFJ5G1.5","plat","graviteits"}],
 "2":[{"2","HHJ5S2.5","holle plunjer","veer"}],
 "3":[{"3","HTJ5S7.5","inbouw","veer"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your PHP code a tad bit. Try doing something like this:

```php
$productarray = array();
while ($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // NOTE: using associative array
    $productarray[] = $product;
}
echo json_encode($productarray);

// Output
// [{
//     "product_id": "1",
//     "product_model": "HFJ5G1.5",
//     "product_type": "plat",
//     "product_rturn": "graviteits"
// }, {
//     "product_id": "2",
//     "product_model": "HHJ5S2.5",
//     "product_type": "holle plunjer",
//     "product_rturn": "veer"
// }, {
//     "product_id": "3",
//     "product_model": "HTJ5S7.5",
//     "product_type": "inbouw",
//     "product_rturn": "veer"
// }]
```

Notice that it now becomes very easy to iterate. You can do so as follows:

```javascript
var o = [{
    "product_id": "1",
    "product_model": "HFJ5G1.5",
    "product_type": "plat",
    "product_rturn": "graviteits"
}, {
    "product_id": "2",
    "product_model": "HHJ5S2.5",
    "product_type": "holle plunjer",
    "product_rturn": "veer"
}, {
    "product_id": "3",
    "product_model": "HTJ5S7.5",
    "product_type": "inbouw",
    "product_rturn": "veer"
}];
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
    console.log("Product " + (i + 1) + " has model:" + o[i]["product_model"]);
    console.log("Product " + (i + 1) + " has type:" + o[i]["product_type"]);
}
```

Comment: var j = 1;
for(var i in o){
alert(o[i][j]); /*it needs to alert each and every value right*/
j++
}

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $productarray[$i]['id'] = $row['product_id'];
    $productarray[$i]['model'] = $row['product_model'];
    $productarray[$i]['type'] = $row['product_type'];
    $productarray[$i]['ret'] = $row['product_return'];
$i++;
}

$jsonstring = json_encode($productarray);
```

the JSON will look like this:

```
[
 {id:"1",model:"HFJ5G1.5",type:"plat",ret:"graviteits"},
 {id:"2",model:"HHJ5S2.5",type:"holle plunjer",ret:"veer"},
 {id:"3",model:"HTJ5S7.5",type:"inbouw",ret:"veer"}
]
```

now in JS you can loop like:

```
for(i=0,i<jsonString.length;i++;){
   id    = jsonString[i].id;
   model = jsonString[i].model;
   type  = jsonString[i].type;
   ret   = jsonString[i].ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first string is valid JSON, the second is not. You can check online (see google, there are JSON syntax check websites) or in a browser console with window.JSON.parse() (any modern browser, older browsers don't have window.JSON). Since this is an object you can iterate with

```
for (var i in o) {
  //do something with o[i]
}
```

Or you could just change the {} for [] and remove the key strings '"":' and have an array:

```
//Input JSON string:
//[
//  ["1","HFJ5G1.5","plat","graviteits"],
//  ["2","HHJ5S2.5","holle plunjer","veer"],
//  ["3","HTJ5S7.5","inbouw","veer"]
//]
JSON.parse('[["1","HFJ5G1.5","plat","graviteits"],["2","HHJ5S2.5","holle plunjer","veer"],["3","HTJ5S7.5","inbouw","veer"]]')
//(to test it - works.)
```

Comment: Could those who downvote something (like this here to -1) please explain WHY? I cannot see anything wrong with my explanation (also, the examples parse!). or was it the guy I added a comment "Strange question" to, as retribution??? (that Q has now disappeared). If so: you DO have some serious issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 "1":[{"1","HFJ5G1.5","plat","graviteits"}],
 "2":[{"2","HHJ5S2.5","holle plunjer","veer"}],
 "3":[{"3","HTJ5S7.5","inbouw","veer"}]
}
```

is not a correct object. When you have a '{}', you need to have a set of 'name:value' separated by coma inside.

So you may have:

```
{
 "1":["1","HFJ5G1.5","plat","graviteits"],
 "2":["2","HHJ5S2.5","holle plunjer","veer"],
 "3":["3","HTJ5S7.5","inbouw","veer"]
}
```

or

```
{
 "1":[{nameField1:"1",nameField2:"HFJ5G1.5",nameField3:"plat",nameField4:"graviteits"}], // one object in the array
 ...
}
```